# How to design dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I want to design form with many fields. Some fields are dependent on the first drop-down list.
How to design to show only those that are needed?

Comment: I fear that response is 'by hand using jquery'.

Comment: I want to design valid django class with all fields and show only required

Comment: A solution may be set dependant inputs as hidden and change by visible  control with jquery when needed.

Comment: You should use Javascript and may be AJAX.

Comment: Why about -1? Please, post a message with down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **hide those that you might not be needed in CSS**.

Then, you should create some **javascript to show/hide fields depending on the value of the select**. Example with jQuery:

```
$('select[name=yourselect]').change(function() {
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'someval':
            $('input[name=somefield]').show();
            $('input[name=someotherfield]').hide();
            break;
         // add as many cases as you want, one for each value
    }
})

// this is useful when your select has an initial value, 
// to show/hide the fields depending on the initially selected option
$('select[name=yourselect]').trigger('change');
```

You can also make [server side checks with your form clean() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a dynamic form in multiple steps in which second form depends on first forms values then you can use Django Form Wizard. This is good if you don't want to use jquery. In this way you can also apply customized clean function for individual forms.

Check the [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) documentation. I hope this will be useful for you.